# Canvas Element Rendering killed after updating an attribute

Tags: javascript, canvas, polymer

```
<polymer-element name="canvas-diagram" attributes="type width height json">
  <template>
    <div id="canvasField">
        Typ: {{type}}, Width:{{width}}, Height:{{height}}, json:{{json}}
        <div id="canvasContainer">
            <canvas id="canvasObj" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}"></canvas>
        </div>    
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
        return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
    }
    Polymer("canvas-diagram",{
        type: "bar",
        width: "300",
        height: "200",
        ready: function() {
            console.log("this.ready()");

            this.writeDiagram();
        },
        attributeChanged: function(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
            console.log("this.attributeChanged()");

            this.writeDiagram();
        },
        writeDiagram : function(){
            console.log("this.writeDiagram()");

            if(typeof this.cv == "undefined"){
                this.cv = this.$.canvasObj.getContext("2d");
            }

            var values = new Array();
            for (var i=0; i<this.json.data.length;i++)
            {
                if(this.json.data[i].value)
                {
                    values.push(this.json.data[i].value*1);
                }
                else
                {
                    values.push(0);
                }
            }

            tmpBarLeft = 15;
            tmpBarWidth = (this.width-30)/values.length-10;

            for (var i=0; i<this.json.data.length;i++)
            {
                tmpBarHeight = this.json.data[i].value*1/getMaxOfArray(values) * (this.height-2*10-20);
                tmpBarTop = this.height-tmpBarHeight - 15;

                this.cv.fillStyle = "#aaa";
                this.cv.fillRect(tmpBarLeft, tmpBarTop, tmpBarWidth, tmpBarHeight);

                tmpBarLeft+=(tmpBarWidth+10);

            }
            console.log("rendering complete");

        },

      json: {
        data:[
            {"name":"Texts","value":"150"},
            {"name":"Videos","value":"50"},
            {"name":"Audio","value":"30"},
            {"name":"Test","value":"20"},
            {"name":"Test","value":"20"},
            {"name":"Test","value":"20"}
        ]}
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GdbN7JVPSKSTItEfIFLG?p=preview

There is a simple rendering of some values. But when I set the attribute height or width to another value the rendering starts but shortly after that everything turns blanc. I have absolutely no idea why. The console shows an "undefined" but no idea where this is from. Not from my code.

Comment: It's because resizing the canvas element will automatically erase all its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attibuteChanged method is firing before the canvas can redraw itself and therefore it's also clearing the next writeDiagram() draw operation.

You could use the built in Polymer Async method to allow the canvas to clear the screen before redrawing like this:

```
attributeChanged: function(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
 console.log("this.attributeChanged()");

 this.async(function() {
    this.writeDiagram();
 });        
}
```